# My colors in iphone different that my colors in my miniMac?

Tags: ios, iphone, colors

I perform UI design on my Mac mini but when I add the images to my iPhone the colors appear different.

When I take a color like #f2f2f2 and use it in my app it will be look different.

How can I sync colors on my iPhone screen and Mac mini screen to see the same colors?
[I want to design my UI first in Photoshop and after this add him to my application.

My screen:

brightness/contrast: 75% / 75%

input color format: RGB

gamma: mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you [calibrated](http://spyder.datacolor.com) your screen?

Although it will be impossible to get an exact color correct implementation on your design in Photoshop, if you calibrate your screen first on your Mac mini you should be on the road to getting it close to what you want.

Unfortunately there is no free way to get a calibrated screen. You can play with your color profiles in System preferences->Display->Color->Select a profile but it will be a fair way off if you're wanting it to be perfect.